# How to count frequncy of words from a list in a dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, cpu-word

If I have a dataframe with the following layout:

```
ID#      Response
1234     Covid-19 was a disaster for my business
3456     The way you handled this pandemic was awesome
```

I want to be able to count frequency of specific words from a list.

```
list=['covid','COVID','Covid-19','pandemic','coronavirus']
```

In the end I want to generate a dictionary like the following

```
{covid:0,COVID:0,Covid-19:1,pandemic:1,'coronavirus':0}
```

Please help I am really stuck on how to code this in python

Comment: Given input text `covid covid covid` in one row, is that three or one?

Comment: that should be 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each string, find number of matches.

```
dict((s, df['response'].str.count(s).fillna(0).sum()) for s in list_of_strings)
```

Note that `Series.str.count` takes a regex input. You may want to append `(?=\b)` for positive look-ahead word-endings.

`Series.str.count` returns `NA` when counting `NA`, thus, fill with 0. For each string, sum over column.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'sheet':['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet2'],
    'tokenized_text':[['efcc', 'fficial', 'billiontwits', 'since', 'covid', 'landed'], ['when', 'people', 'say', 'the', 'fatality', 'rate', 'of', 'coronavirus', 'is'], ['in', 'the', 'coronavirus-induced', 'crisis', 'people', 'are',  'cyvbwx'], ['in', 'the', 'be-induced', 'crisis', 'people', 'are',  'cyvbwx']] })

print(df)

words_collection = ['covid','COVID','Covid-19','pandemic','coronavirus']

# Extract the words from all lines
all_words = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    all_words.extend(row['tokenized_text'])

# Create a dictionary that maps for each word from `words_collection` the counter it appears
word_to_number_of_occurences = dict()

# Go over the word collection and set it's counter
for word in words_collection:
    word_to_number_of_occurences[word] = all_words.count(word)

# {'covid': 1, 'COVID': 0, 'Covid-19': 0, 'pandemic': 0, 'coronavirus': 1}
print(word_to_number_of_occurences)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `np.hstack` and `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

a = np.hstack(df['Response'].str.split())
dct = {**dict.fromkeys(lst, 0), **Counter(a[np.isin(a, lst)])}
```

---

```
{'covid': 0, 'COVID': 0, 'Covid-19': 1, 'pandemic': 1, 'coronavirus': 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it very simply with a dict of comprehension :

```
{x:df.Response.str.count(x).sum() for x in list}
```

Output

```
{'covid': 0, 'COVID': 0, 'Covid-19': 1, 'pandemic': 1, 'coronavirus': 0}
```